# Yocto: cmake is missing header - how to DEPEND dev-package?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, yocto, bitbake

I am including `opencv` with custom build parameters in my Yocto image. For that I have an `opencv_4.1.0.bbappend` recipe, in which I set custom options, specifically `FFMPEG`. The recipe goes something like this:

```
DEPENDS += "ffmpeg libpng"
EXTRA_OECMAKE_append += "-DWITH_FFMPEG=ON -DWITH_GTK=OFF"  # and some other options
```

During `configure` I get cmake errors and can't seem to figure out, how to satisfy the header dependencies. The errors go like this (I assume this is the reason for `do_configure` to fail):

```
CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: /home/janos/dev/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/opencv/4.1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/libpng/png.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include </home/janos/dev/yocto/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/opencv/4.1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/libpng/png.h>

CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <sys/videoio.h>
```

Focusing on the missing `png.h` header first, I am tempted to depend `libpng-dev`, as I also would `apt install` it. But there is no package for it.

When I search `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p libpng`, I can find the header in a `libpng-dev` package:

```
...
libpng-dev:
    /usr/bin/libpng-config
    /usr/bin/libpng16-config
    /usr/include/libpng16/png.h
    /usr/include/libpng16/pngconf.h
    /usr/include/libpng16/pnglibconf.h
    /usr/include/png.h
    ...
...
```

I can also find it in `libpng-src` and also `ffmpeg-src` package (`oe-pkgdata-util find-path "*png.h"` was my friend). But all of these -dev and -src packages I cannot depend on in `DEPENDS`.

How can I get my recipe to know those headers?

Target machine is `raspberrypi4-64`, on which the recipe is configuring and compiling well - it fails when I build for `qemux86-64`, which I use for testing. Namely, my test command is `MACHINE="qemux86-64" bitbake opencv`.

Comment: The header file is at a different path: missing `recipe-sysroot/usr/include/libpng/png.dev` and the file in the library is at `libpng16/png.h`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really answer the question which I though was the question - but this is how the `opencv` recipe is easily configured:

```
PACKAGECONFIG = "python3 libav libv4l v4l"
```

Looking into [the opencv 4.1.0 recipe](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/123292/) ([opencv_4.1.0.bb](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/opencv/opencv_4.1.0.bb?h=dunfell)), I could see that `FFMPEG` gets enabled with the `libav` configurable option.

As a result of depending `FFMEPG`, I had to whitelist *"commercial"* licenses in my `local.conf` file:

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial"
```

Looking into `./build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/4.1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure` shows that opencv is correctly configured without GUI, with v4l/v4l2:, FFMPEG, python3, etc.

And so `python3` in the resulting image:

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```